# FIXED - AfterEffect graph editor is stuck on displaying one particular curve and does not refresh

Tags: after-effects

[image]

The graph editor constantly displays the curves for the positions of a puppet pin, even when I'm not selecting anything and when I select something else.

Deleting the layer will get rid of it. But I want to find an alternative because I've spent a lot of time animating the pin.

Does anyone have any ideas?

FIXED:  It seems to be a bug with AE. My solution was by just duplicating the old layer and then deleting the old layer.

Comment: Please put your solution into an answer, not the question. You can accept your own answer. That way it will be easier to find the solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with AE. My solution was by just duplicating the old layer and then deleting the old layer.